# Scheduled reminders if drivers are late

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, cron

I have to create a system that checks 30 minutes before an estimated arrival time if the driver will make it based on Google Directions API time parameter and if not alert a call center agent.

What is the best way to do this I thought of using cron jobs but I would need to set like 2000+ cron jobs a day to meet the demand and there might be 2-3 jobs that need to run at once every 1 minute to 30 seconds.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a daemon process in **PHP/CLI** that can [fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) or launch [threads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) to do a specific jobs scheduled/managed by your main process

Using this technique, Cron Job will only start your process (after system reboot) and nothing else